# sql server query partitioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to get all the rows of a table's partition using the partition key column and not the partition number?

```
select * from partitioned_table
where $partition.fpartfunction(key_column) = 1
```

As far as i know the above returns all rows in partition 1. I wonder if i could do something similar like this:

PSEUDO CODE :

```
select * from partitioned_table
    where $partition.get_me_all_rows_in_partition_with_Keycolumn_year = '2019'
```

Comment: You want to find the partition containing year 2019 and then get all rows belonging to that partition (Which may include other years?) - yes. you can use the DMVs to work out what partition a value would fall into if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all rows from a partition using the partitioning column instead of the partition function directly, specify a `WHERE` clause matching the actual partition boundaries. SQL Server using range partitioning so you'll need to specify the lower boundary value (except for the first partition) and the upper boundary value (except for the last partition).

The lower boundary predicate needs to be `>` with a `RANGE LEFT` partition function because the partition boundary is exclusive of the boundary value. Conversely, the lower boundary predicate needs to be `>=` with a `RANGE RIGHT` partition function because the partition boundary is exclusive of the boundary value.

Below are examples with yearly partitions on a `date` data type partitioning column.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date(date) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES('2019-01-01','2020-01-01');

--first partition
SELECT *
FROM dbo.partitioned_table
WHERE key_column <= '2019-01-01';
--second partition
SELECT *
FROM dbo.partitioned_table
WHERE key_column > '2019-01-01' AND key_column <= '2020-01-01';
--last partition
SELECT *
FROM dbo.partitioned_table
WHERE key_column > '2020-01-01';

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date(date) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES('2019-01-01','2020-01-01');

--first partition
SELECT *
FROM dbo.partitioned_table
WHERE key_column < '2019-01-01';
--second partition
SELECT *
FROM dbo.partitioned_table
WHERE key_column >= '2019-01-01' AND key_column < '2020-01-01';
--last partition
SELECT *
FROM dbo.partitioned_table
WHERE key_column >= '2020-01-01';
```